# Git push force to update a branch

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a project directory(without git folder) where I am working and trying to update an existing remote branch forcefully.

Steps I have taken -

```
1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit "Fresh update after changing db"
4. git remote add origin <repo_url>
5. git push origin staging
```

And I get the below error -

```
error: src refspec staging does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to '<repo_url>'
```

When I do `git branch -a` it doesn't show all the branches just only `master`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Take the pull after adding remote.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I do not want to pull the remote branch as that one is messed up. I want to do fresh update.

Comment: Please check below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take pull after adding remote:

```
1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit "Fresh update after changing db"
4. git remote add origin <repo_url>
5. git checkout -b staging
6. git fetch
7. git push -f origin staging
```

> Avoid using force push if possible. Let me know exact scenario for better solution.

Comment: Done. Now I can see all the branches but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Prithviraj is staging branch present on remote?

Comment: Also check answer by masseyb

Comment: Also check answer by masseyb

Answer (score 1):

You're on the `master` branch and trying to push to the remote `staging` branch. You should `git checkout -b staging` locally before committing and pushing the changes:

```
git init
git add .
git checkout -b staging
git commit "Fresh update after changing db"
git remote add origin <repo_url>
git push origin staging
```